# Api to post image on CrowdFlower's RTFM

Tags: android, iphone

I am working with an android iphone app. I have to post user uploaded image on CrowdFlower's RTFM for auto approval. I don't know api that will post image on RTFM.

Is any one know api for this. If yes, please provide steps to post image on CrowdFlower's RTFM.

Thanks.

Comment: RTFM: https://crowdflower.com/docs/rtfm

Comment: I already check this site. Created api like in example and execute it but not return any result.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use Parse's module to post images to RTFM:

http://blog.crowdflower.com/2012/12/announcing-our-new-cloud-module-partnership-with-parse/

You can also use RTFM's API directly, as Geobits pointed out, or their [Ruby API](https://github.com/dolores/rtfm-ruby/) from your servers.

Comment: Actually I was try api of RTFM with command line curl format. After convert it into php curl format, it worked properly.                                                                      Thanks for your answer.